# Does asp.net web application remain running when uploaded on a web server?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to figure out whether my application remain running when it is in a web server. Now that we know from Visual Studio is that you could run the app on localhost and you can stop it.

The situation is that in my app, I have a `Global.asax` where on `Application Start` defined a `Timer` for 2 minutes and then execute a `Sub` which sends an email.

My question is, if a user requests `Main.aspx` and then `Global.asax` is initiated, does `Global.asax` get re-initiated every time a user requests `Main.aspx`? or does it maintain the 2 minutes interval regardles of whether `Main.aspx` is called or its idle? In other means as per the title of this post Does `Main.aspx` stops as per the Visual Studio `stop` button whenever a user leaves the web app? and if so, does `Global.asax` gets affected or stopped by that?

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @GJKH's answer:

If you're running IIS 7.5 or 8, then you can turn on the Always On option in the config `applicationhost.config`.

In IIS in the Application Pool Settings for Start Mode, set it to Always Running.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware by default IIS will shut down (recycle) the worker pool that the site is attached to if it isn't accessed for more than 20 minutes. This setting can be changed and there are tools that will help keep the site 'alive'.

The code in Application_Start in the global.asax file will only fire once when the application is started and loaded into the pool. Accessing any page on the site will not fire it again. When the pool is recycled and a page is requested, the application will start again and Application_start will be fired.

What I'm not sure of is if the timer you have set will keep the application alive. My guess is it won't.

**Edit:**

The timer won't keep the site alive, this might be of help (from http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive)

```
 public void PingServer()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient http = new WebClient();
            string Result = http.DownloadString(App.Configuration.PingUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

And on Application Exit call

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    // Force the App to be restarted immediately
    new YourClassName().PingServer();
}
```

Problem with this approach is the timer wont be accurate as it will be disposed of when the pool tries to recycle and then started again.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a bad idea to use timers in a web application.  The reason is that you never know when IIS will decide to recycle the app pool worker thread.  Also, timers are likely going to be global and not user specific, so you can't use things like Session or other user specific data.

If you need to run a task, then you should create a windows service that does that task.